# Understanding this memoize decorator

Tags: python

I am having trouble understanding this memoize decorator

```
def method(func):
    """
    Decorator for caching parameterless bound method
    """
    key = '_memoize_%s' % func.__name__
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self):
        if not hasattr(self, key):
            setattr(self, key, func(self))
        return getattr(self, key)

    return wrapper
```

Let's say I have:

```
@method
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
```

Is it attaching a key `_memoize_add` to the tuple (x,y), since that's what's being passed to the wrapper.

Comment: where did you find this decorator? For memoization see http://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php

Comment: @shx2  no I found it while brosing here https://github.com/tangleon/tangleon/blob/master/tangleon/memoize.py

Comment: @Griffosx I found this browsing the source code for a website here: https://github.com/tangleon/tangleon/blob/master/tangleon/memoize.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decorator stores the return value of a method as a private attribute. So it will only work with a class instance, and not with an ordinary function.

The `func` argument of the decorator is the method it is wrapping, and the returned `wrapper` function will end up being called instead of the method. When the wrapper is called, its `self` argument will be the instance of the class, and so the `settattr` call will cache the result of `func` as a private attribute named by `key`. After that, all further calls will return the cached value of the `key` attribute instead.

Here's a simple test that shows how it could be used:

```
import random
from functools import wraps

def method(func):
    key = '_memoize_%s' % func.__name__
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self):
        if not hasattr(self, key):
            setattr(self, key, func(self))
        return getattr(self, key)

    return wrapper

class Test(object):
    @method
    def cached(self):
        return random.random()

    def uncached(self):
        return random.random()

t = Test()
for x in range(3):
    print('cached: %s' % t.cached())
    print('uncached: %s' % t.uncached())
print(t.__dict__)
```

Output:

```
cached: 0.6594806157188309
uncached: 0.2492466307551897
cached: 0.6594806157188309
uncached: 0.08718572660830726
cached: 0.6594806157188309
uncached: 0.5501638352647334
{'_memoize_cached': 0.6594806157188309}
```